How to setup Clion to follow child process, permanently
I do know how to follow child proccess in gdb but, I don't want to setup gdb every time. So is it a way of making the debugger of Clion follow child every time ?
I use for now the following commands :
set detach-on-fork off
set follow-fork-mode child

I have to write them in gbd every time I start the debugger of Clion.

I don't use clion myself, but normally GDB will load the ~/.gdbinit file from your home directory and run all the commands in that file.
It is possible that clion specifically passes an option to GDB to tell it NOT to load that file .... but I'd try just adding those two lines to your .gdbinit file and see if that works.
See here for more details on GDB's init files.
